# Не получается получить значение элемента массива

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Приветствую. Есть стандартный глобальный массив `$product` в результате вывода которого:

```
var_dump($product);
```

получаем:

```
object(WC_Product_Variable)#7818 (13) { ["children"]=> NULL ["total_stock"]=> NULL ["id"]=> int(3309) ["post"]=> object(WP_Post)#7820 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(3309) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2015-06-30 17:37:07" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2015-06-30 14:37:07" ["post_content"]=> string(883) "Описание бла-бла-бла" ["post_title"]=> string(39) "Название" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(508)
```

Хочу обратиться к элементу `["post_content"]`, но ни так `var_dump($product["post_content"])`, ни так `var_dump($product->post_content)`, ни так `var_dump($product->post_content())` не получается
А как правильно нужно?

Comment: $product->post->post_content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас объект содержит вложенный объект.

```
$post = $product->post;
$post->post_content;
```

Но я советую использовать функцию, для получения поста по ID `get_post()` [подробно](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/)

```
$post = get_post( 110 );
$content = $post->post_content;
```

то же самое в виде массива

```
$post = get_post( 100, ARRAY_A);
$content = $post['post_content'];
```

Comment: ,а если я обращаюсь к `$product->post->post_excerpt`, а на выходе получаю `string(208) "текст"` как избавиться от кавычек и `string`

Comment: вы видимо var_dump'ом выводите. Используйте echo $product->post->post_excerpt